# UIApplication -scheduleLocalNotification: very slow when called by UIApplication -appWillTerminate:

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

[image: time profiler of my app when i press home button]

I set the "application does not run in background" in my `info.plist`, so when user tap home button, app quits.

When my  `[UIApplication -appWillTerminate:]` called, I will schedule 64 local notifications to system, all of them are non-repeating.

but that take a seemingly long time(6.17 seconds) on a iPhone4 with iOS6.0.1.
When I look at the time profiler, I found that the curve is very strange, it don't take much CPU time, but it do take a lot of time.

Also when I look at the call tree, 93% of the time is spent on `[UIApplication -scheduleLocalNotification:]` in the time range showed in the image.
Why?

This is how I generate my notifications:

```
UILocalNotification *n = [[[UILocalNotification] alloc] init] autorelease];
n.alertBody = @"some body";
n.hasAction = YES;
n.alertAction = @"some action";
n.fireDate = @"some date";
n.repeatInterval = 0;
n.soundName = @"my sound"
n.userInfo = aDictionaryWithAStringAbount10CharacterLongAnd2NSNumber.
[self.notifications addObject:n];
```

This is how I schedule my notifications:

```
-(void)endProxyAndWriteToSystemLocalNotification
{
        _proxying = NO;
        NSDate *dateAnchor = [NSDate date];

        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [self.notifications objectEnumerator];
        NSInteger i = 0;
        while (i < maxLocalNotifCount) {
            UILocalNotification *n = [enumerator nextObject];
            if (!d) {
                break;
            }

            if ([n.fireDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateAnchor] >= 0) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:n];
                i++;
            }
        }

        [self.notificationDatas removeAllObjects];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would help:

```
-(void)endProxyAndWriteToSystemLocalNotification {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:self.notifications];
}
```

iOS 4.2 and later

read UIApplication Class Reference for detailed description

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to schedule 64 local notifications. Is there a reason to do all of these on app termination? Apples scheduleLocalNotification was not designed to be called so many times on termination

Comment: I do need to do this, is there any good idea for enhance the performance of this?

Comment: @Dwayne why do you need to do 64 local notifications?

Comment: I'm working on some kind of task management app. It need to notify the user when the app isn't running. Also it involves network sync, so that it may download a lot of tasks in a short time. And it will be a burst of scheduling local notifications at that time.

Comment: And why does this need to occur in the appWillTerminate method?

Comment: When the app is front running, scheduling local notification is also slow, which will freeze UI, so I wrote a proxy to queue the local notifications and schedule them when my app quits. Also I set "Application Does Not Run In Background" in my info.plist for other reason.

Comment: sounds like you may be scheduling local notifications incorrectly. post some code